# ***Reading from file in C*** using fscanf, Scanning and printing a char that doesn't exist in .txt file

Tags: c, io, scanf

Hello Everyone and Thank You for clicking!(Hate being stuck)

I'm trying to fscanf a char value from one file to a variable in my struct. 
When I scan I get a completely different letter than the one I'm trying to get. The problem is in my readfile function. If I get past this problem I hope I can scan numbers that I'll need to do arithmetic with is possible. My professor is teaching us FCFS (pertaining to OS scheduling algorithms not a FCFS data structure queue lesson). So the text files columns mean (PAS.txt):

Process Name  | Arrival Time | Service Time

```
   A    0   3
   B    2   6
   C    4   4
   D    6   5
   E    8   2
```

---

```
//Main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "lab8Func.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

struct FCFS process;

readFile(&process);

printf("%s",&process.jobList[0].processName)

 }
```

---

```
//lab8func.h
#ifndef lab8Func_h
#define lab8Func_h
struct Job
{
    char processName;
    int arrivalTime;
    int serviceTime;
    int TAT;
    int NTAT;

};

struct FCFS
{
    struct Job jobList[5];

};

void readFile(struct FCFS*);

#endif /* lab8Func_h */
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lab8Func.h"


void readFile(struct FCFS *process1)
{  
FILE *file;
char temp;
int tempAT;
int tempST;



if((file = fopen("/Users/Vin/desktop/PAS.txt","r")) == NULL)
printf("Error, File Not Open.");
else
 {


    for(int i=0 ; i < 1; i++)
     {

         temp = fscanf(file," %c", &temp);  // where I'm stuck..
         process1->jobList[i].processName = temp;


        }


    }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
bProgram ended with exit code: 0
```

***lowercase b ?? How ? I'm looking for capital A!!*****

Comment: 1) `fscanf` returns  number of elements successfully read. `temp = fscanf(file," %c", &temp);` --> `fscanf(file, " %c", &temp);`

Comment: 2) `printf("%s",&process.jobList[0].processName)` --> `printf("%c", process.jobList[0].processName)`

Comment: the function: `main()` has two valid signatures.  Those signatures are: `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  and `int main( void )`.   When the passed parameters are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`.   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11 )

Comment: in the function: `readFile()`, the local variables `tempAt` and `tempSt` are not being used, so should be removed.

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`..  When the error indication comes from a system function (like: fopen()) then use `perror( "fopen failed" );`   That will output the message to `stderr` and output the associated text that indicates why the system thinks the function failed.

Comment: when calling system functions like fopen() and fscanf(), always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Note: `fscanf()` returns an integer that contains the number of successful input/format specifiers that were successfully input or EOF.  It does NOT return a `char`.  The `&temp` parameter gets the value read in from(in this case) `file`.  Assigning the returned value from the function to `temp` just overlays `temp` with some 1 byte integer value.  Suggest: `if( 1 != fscanf(file," %c", &temp) )  { // handle error  and exit }`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: this input example line: `A    0   3` shows there are 3 entries on each line, not just a single character, so in the function: `readFile()`, need to finish reading the line.

Comment: in C, ,most code block ends in a semicolon, including single statements like: `printf("%s",&process.jobList[0].processName)` need a `;` at the end

Comment: variable and parameter names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  The parameter `process1` does neither.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to `#include` header files when the content of that header file is not used.  I.E. the header file: `time.h`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the return value of fscanf is the number of arguments successfully written (or EOF on failure).  So you are overwriting your temp variable.

```
temp = fscanf(file," %c", &temp);
```

Secondly, this print statement is wrong:

```
printf("%s",&process.jobList[0].processName)
```

%s means to print a null terminated string and you are passing it a pointer to a char.  They are both of type char * which is why it compiles, but they way you are calling can't be expected to work and may crash.

```
printf("%c",process.jobList[0].processName)
```

Thirdly, you are forgetting to read all three columns inside your loop with fscanf.

Comment: I know I didn't read all columns the loop only goes once, if I can't get the first char I'm not going to try integers. Okay I'll change that "s" to a "c".

Answer (score 2):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. cleans up after it self (in this case closes the input file
3. checks for and handles errors
4. outputs error messages to `stderr` rather than `stdout`
5. exits when a problem is incountered
6. does not contain 'magic' numbers.  I.E. the hard coded '5'
7. reads up to 5 lines from the input file, instead of just one line
8. corrects the (several) syntax errors in the posted code
9. preforms the desired functionality
10. still uses `fscanf()` although a better call would be `fgets()` as that would eliminate the code block containing `getc()`
11. eliminates unneeded local variables
12. uses the correct signature for the `main()` function
13. documents why each header file is included
14. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
15. keeps variable declaration local to where it is being used.
16. makes some effort to improve the 'meaning' of the passed variable to the function: `readFile()`

Caveat: I modified the code layout (for my convenience) to all be in a single file

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), fclose(), fscanf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
//#include <time.h>
//#include "lab8Func.h"

//lab8func.h
#ifndef lab8Func_h
#define lab8Func_h

#define MAX_RECORDS 5

struct Job
{
    char processName;
    int  arrivalTime;
    int  serviceTime;
    int  TAT;
    int  NTAT;

};

struct FCFS
{
    struct Job jobList[ MAX_RECORDS ];
};

void readFile(struct FCFS*);

#endif /* lab8Func_h */



int main( void )
{
    struct FCFS jobs;

    readFile(&jobs);

    printf("%c", jobs.jobList[0].processName);
} // end function: main


void readFile(struct FCFS *jobs)
{
    FILE *file = NULL;

    if((file = fopen("/Users/Vin/desktop/PAS.txt","r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    for(int i=0 ; i < MAX_RECORDS; i++)
    {
        char temp;
        if( 1 != fscanf(file," %c", &temp ) )
        { // handle error and exit
             perror( "fscanf failed" );
             fclose( file );  // cleanup
             exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fscanf successful

        jobs->jobList[i].processName = temp;

        // finish inputting the current line from the file
        int ch;
        while( (ch = getc( file ) ) != EOF && '\n' != ch )
        {
            ;
        }
    }

    fclose( file );   // cleanup
}  // end function:  readFile
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing should be kept in mind that you should always look at `fscanf` or `scanf` for `checking` if its returning true or false(any integer value or 0) i.e it is reading in correct format or not, and then process further.

You need to modify your code in for loop of readFile function:

```
   if((check=fscanf(file," %c", &temp))>0) 
      process1->jobList[i].processName = temp;
```

Comment: Great that makes perfect sense, I will change it. Thank you!